# Google Apps Script: Avoid urlfetch errors by updating to a Standard GCP

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have a very simple question which is if we can avoid the error:

> Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch.

by attaching our Google Apps Script to a Google Cloud Project?

The current quota is 20K to 100K a day depending if you have a Free or a Google Workspace account.

At this point I would be OK if I had to pay Google for any executions over the limit. Is it possible?

The steps I've taken so far:

- Create GCP project
- Link Google Apps Script to GCP project
- Set up the OAuth of the GCP project

In case it is possible I think I'm missing an additional step to confirm Google I'd like to pay for any extra processing time that the GAS project requires, can anyone please confirm/point me to an example on how to set it up?

**UPDATE:**

I'm starting to look if that quota can be modified on this IAM & Admin -> Quotas section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on your Quotas page at your GCP project:

[Cloud Functions Quotas Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com&usage=ALL&project=_)

When you reach a quota limit
When a function consumes all of an allocated resource, the resource becomes unavailable until the quota is refreshed or increased. This may mean that your function and all other functions in the same project will not work until then. A function returns an HTTP 500 error code when one of the resources is over quota and the function cannot execute.

To increase quotas above the defaults listed here, go to the Cloud Functions Quotas Page, select the quotas you want to modify, click EDIT QUOTAS, supply your user information if prompted, and enter the new quota limit for each quota you selected.

i don't know if your project is firebase related, but can take a look at complete article about quotas in this link:

[Quotas and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas)

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, my project is a script that make calls to an external API. This calls to an API 20K-100K limit. You think you tell me which service should I check for this type of quota?

Comment: you can try sorting the Quota Status colum, by hitting the arrow aside the name, you may get the quotas that are Out of limit.

[Rate Limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits)

<img src="blob:chrome-untrusted://media-app/916e928c-7fdf-47d6-b40a-121f2fbd9ef1" alt="Screenshot 2021-04-22 10.39.33 AM.png"/>

Comment: This is as well a quotas monitoring guide, that may help you to identify the one you need to request the increase for:

[Working with Qoutas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota)